# ASPNETBOILERPLATE - App service method not returning related entities in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am in the process of converting my .NET MVC5 template into .NET Core MVC template of ASPNETZERO. So all the code I am converting is working just as I need in my MVC5 template solution. My method code is shown below.

```
  public async Task<EditCompanyDto> GetCompanyForEdit(NullableIdDto input)
    {
        var companyEditDto = (await _companyRepository.GetAsync((int)input.Id));
        var cmp = companyEditDto.MapTo<EditCompanyDto>();
        return cmp;
    }
```

This code works perfectly in the MVC5 template and returns the related entities of Address, Contact and Note. In the .NET Core solution this exact same code returns only the Address and Contact collections in the above method. It keeps returning the Note collection as NULL.

Shown below is my company entity. I have removed some fields for this post, but have left all the navigational properties.

```
public class Company : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{

    public string CompanyTaxId { get; set; }

    public bool ActiveYesNo { get; set; }

    public virtual NoteHeader Note { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CompanyAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CompanyContact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Addresses = new List<CompanyAddress>();
        Contacts = new List<CompanyContact>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Lazy loading is not supported by EF Core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that limitation. However, contacts and address collections are being returned with my GetAsync() call. It is just the note entity that is coming back null.I dont understand that?

Comment: @exlnt you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403796/6527049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say **Note collection**. As far as i see Note **is not** collection. Let's assume it's collection.
Gabriel's approach is correct. But didn't include Note field. As a result your code should be like this

```
var company = _companyRepository.GetAll()
                                .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                                .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                                .Include(c => c.Note)
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.Id);
```

**Note:** GetAll() doesn't mean you grab all data from database. GetAll() returns IQueryable. So, you can add Linq methods after it. But if you use GetAllList(), yes it fetches all data from table.

Answer (score 2):

Try to load your collection by using the [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) method.

You can use it like this:

```
var company = _companyRepository.GetAll()
                                .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                                .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the lazy loading feature being N/A in .Net core. I also did find the include method. However my concern with using this approach is what this will do to performance of my app, if every "GetForEdit" method will use GetAll()? Is that not loading lots of data for no reason? Surely there will a performance price to pay for this.This does not seem like a sustainable design that could scale up, once the app has large volumes of data.

Comment: Your solution did work very nicely, thanks! However the concern over the performance of this option still concerns me.

Comment: @exlnt You can have multiple application service methods. One that will Include collection, the others not.

Comment: I just found the same issue on my UpdateCompany method. Where I have the same code to get current company data: var cmp = await _companyRepository.GetAsync(input.Id); Now I will need to apply the same code here too in order to get the note entity. This does not seem like a good solution if I have to start applying the GetAll in multiple methods.

Answer (score 1):

@Alper Thanks! The NoteHeader entity contains a collection of NoteDetails, that is where the note collection is. I already implemented @Gabriel's code suggestion and actually added to it, to get exactly what I needed.

```
var companyEditDto = _companyRepository.GetAll()
                           .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                           .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                           .Include(c => c.Note).ThenInclude(N => N.Notes)
                           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.Id);
```