# Retrieve child entities from CrudAppService in ABP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parent-child, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

The `GetAll` and `Get` methods of the ready-made `CrudAppService` don't include child entities.

Is it possible to modify its behaviour?

## Update

`GetAllIncluding` has some problem if the included entity has a navigation property to the parent; it falls into a sort of circular dependency. Is there any `Attribute` or trick to exclude the navigation property from the serialization? The `[NonSerialized]` attribute does not seem to be applicable to a navigation property.

**PostAppService**:

```
public class PostAppService : CrudAppService<Post, PostDto>, IPostAppService
{
    IRepository<Post> _repository = null;

    public PostAppService(IRepository<Post> repository) : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    protected override IQueryable<Post> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
    {
        return _repository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.Items);
    }
}
```

**PostDto**:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Post))]
public class PostDto : EntityDto
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Post** entity:

```
[Table("AbpPosts")]
public class Post : FullAuditedEntity<int,User>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Item** entity:

```
[Table("AbpItems")]
public class Item : Entity
{
    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use eager-loading.

Override `CreateFilteredQuery` and `GetEntityById` in your AppService:

```cs
public class MyAppService : CrudAppService<ParentEntity, ParentEntityDto>, IMyAppService
{
    public MyAppService(IRepository<ParentEntity> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    protected override IQueryable<ParentEntity> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
    {
        return Repository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.ChildEntity);
    }

    protected override ParentEntity GetEntityById(int id)
    {
        var entity = Repository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.ChildEntity).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(ParentEntity), id);
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

The benefit of overriding these methods is that you continue to get [permission checking](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ddbf9f3090f387aeef82183555e875994ddeaff0/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppService.cs#L111), [counting](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ddbf9f3090f387aeef82183555e875994ddeaff0/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppService.cs#L115), [sorting](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ddbf9f3090f387aeef82183555e875994ddeaff0/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppService.cs#L117), [paging](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ddbf9f3090f387aeef82183555e875994ddeaff0/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppService.cs#L118) and [mapping](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ddbf9f3090f387aeef82183555e875994ddeaff0/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppService.cs#L124) for free.

## Update

> `GetAllIncluding` has some problem if the included entity has a navigation property to the parent; it falls into a sort of circular dependency. Is there any `Attribute` or trick to exclude the navigation property from the serialization?

Return `ItemDto` (without navigation property) in `PostDto`.

Comment: Good solution @aaron

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You have to include explicitly like this.

```
GetAll().Include(i => i.ChildEntities)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the child entities manually. It's lazy loading by design.

Comment: do you mean create a method (e.g. myGet)  that use directly the repository invoking entityframwork include comand?
`var events = await _eventRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(e => e.Registrations)
            .WhereIf(!input.IncludeCanceledEvents, e => !e.IsCancelled)
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreationTime)
            .ToListAsync();`

Comment: yeah @alex . that's exactly what I mean

Comment: I did not get why both async and non-async version of CrudService exists. It also confuses me, that non-async versions method are called -Async, deal with Task - so they are kind of "async-ready". So when I am supposed to use one and when another? @vivek-nuna could you please also advice?

Answer (score 0):

For whom that work with **AsyncCrudAppService** and you have two different lists of child:

Below to get specific parent Object with their list of child

```
 protected override Task<Parent> GetEntityByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var entity = Repository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.listOfFirstChild).Include(x => x.listOfSecondChild).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            return base.GetEntityByIdAsync(id);
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you have mixed two approaches together :) You don't use entity anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In Abp.io All You Need Is (that must be added to PostService inherited from **CrudAppService** ):

```
 protected override IQueryable<Post> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
        {
            return _postReposiory
                 .Include(p => p.Item);
        }
```